# Having problem connecting MySQL with Unity3D

Tags: mysql, .net, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity3D. I am trying to connect unity3D with MySQL to build a login and register module. The unity version is 2021.3.16 and MySQL version is 8.0.32. I checked some blogs and import the MySql.data.dll along with some other dlls, shown in the image . I wrote a simple script trying to test the connection

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Data;

public class connectMySql : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        string connectStr = "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;database=test;user=root;password=0121;";
        MySqlConnection coon = new MySqlConnection(connectStr);
        try
        {

            coon.Open();
           
            Debug.Log("success");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log(e.ToString());
        }
       
        coon.Close();
    }

}
```

and the console just reported:

```
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> Mono.Security.Interface.TlsException: Handshake failed - error code: UNITYTLS_INTERNAL_ERROR, verify result: 4294936704
  at Mono.Unity.Debug.CheckAndThrow (Mono.Unity.UnityTls+unitytls_errorstate errorState, Mono.Unity.UnityTls+unitytls_x509verify_result verifyResult, System.String context, Mono.Security.Interface.AlertDescription defaultAlert) [0x00036] in <cb1c94a571d140989f59bc38dfed683a>:0 
  at Mono.Unity.UnityTlsContext.ProcessHandshake () [0x00082] in <cb1c94a571d140989f59bc38dfed683a>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status, System.Boolean renegotiate) [0x000da] in <cb1c94a571d140989f59bc38dfed683a>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake(Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus,bool)
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncHandshakeRequest.Run (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x00006] in <cb1c94a571d140989f59bc38dfed683a>:0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000fc] in <cb1c94a571d140989f59bc38dfed683a>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x0004b] in <cb1c94a571d140989f59bc38dfed683a>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.AuthenticateAsClient(string,System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection,System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols,bool)
  at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x00006] in <cb1c94a571d140989f59bc38dfed683a>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.StartSSL () [0x00035] in <0004ab8b375b422f9000ac25a68089d9>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open () [0x002ce] in <0004ab8b375b422f9000ac25a68089d9>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open () [0x0000b] in <0004ab8b375b422f9000ac25a68089d9>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) [0x0004e] in <0004ab8b375b422f9000ac25a68089d9>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection () [0x00000] in <0004ab8b375b422f9000ac25a68089d9>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection () [0x0008a] in <0004ab8b375b422f9000ac25a68089d9>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver () [0x0003f] in <0004ab8b375b422f9000ac25a68089d9>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection () [0x0001c] in <0004ab8b375b422f9000ac25a68089d9>:0 
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open () [0x0016d] in <0004ab8b375b422f9000ac25a68089d9>:0 
  at connectMySql.Start () [0x0000b] in D:\unity\project\test\Assets\connectMySql.cs:18
```

what am i supposed do to solve this problem? Thanks very much

I searched and did not find useful tips towards this problem. It seems that nobody faced this before, which is very weird. I thought it might happened because that the unity version, MySQL version and .Net version did not match. I tried to use different version of Mysql.data.dll but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think that your:

```
string connectStr = "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;database=test;user=root;password=0121;";
```

Should not have a "**;**" at the end, so it should be something like:

```
string connectStr = "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;database=test;user=root;password=0121";
```

Comment: Thank u for your time, but it didn't work, still facing the same problem.